# earning money online by watching videos online is it haram or halal

Tags: fiqh

I was in this website which pay money online for watching YouTube videos for short time is it hala or haram to earn money through this way

Comment: Why would it be haram? Unless the videos themselves are the source of haram.

Comment: Another obvious thing is that it doesn't stop you from your mandatory religious work.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the content:

If the content has something that is refused by sharia it's totally haram.

If the content is [Mubah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mubah) (permitted), it's halal inshallah.

If the content makes usefulness for you and people, it's halal and you can even get awards from Allah from that Inshallah.

God bless you brother to be more specific on your question.